# Speeding up string concatenation in objective C

Tags: objective-c, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I've determined that manipulating an `NSMutableAttributedString` is the bottleneck of my application. What can I do to speed up building my `NSMutableAttributedString`s? Is there an equivalent to Java's `StringBuilder` for example?

`appendFormat` is the biggest culprit.

Edit: examples, as requested. I could absolutely use straight concatenation in some cases. I had no idea thats faster.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *result = [NSMutableAttributedString new];
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
    [[result mutableString] appendFormat:@"%@=", dataKey];
    NSRange tempRange = NSMakeRange([result length] - [key length], [key length]);
    [result addAttributes:defaultKeyAttributes range:tempRange];

    [[result mutableString] appendFormat:@"%@;", [dict objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Comment: What kind of manipulations are you doing?  Can you replace appendFormat: with simple concatenations?

Comment: Yes, some example snippets would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done any performance testing but here I think is about as good as you can get. Note that you might be able to speed it up even faster by using simpler string concatenation (**see end**) instead of the stringWithFormat. I kept those to keep it closer to your original example.

It represents quite a re-working of your code

1. Avoiding a dictionary lookup for each key by using blocks so the dictionary can do the optimal thing to return both key and value in one hit
2. Building up the string with a preallocated buffer (estimated) then adding all the attributes in one go later
3. Using `setAttributes` rather than `addAttributes` as it's the initial setting of them for a given range, rather than appending (may be more efficient).

The function which does the conversion as did your snippet:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* buildAttributedStringFromDict(NSDictionary* dict, NSDictionary* defaultKeyAttributes)
{
  NSUInteger numPairs = [dict count];
  NSUInteger guessInitialCapacity = numPairs * 20;  // use a multiplier based on your domain to avoid string expansions
  NSMutableString* builder = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:guessInitialCapacity];
  NSRange ranges[numPairs];
  NSRange* rp = ranges;  // use pointer to refer to C array because compiler won't let us put __block on it
  __block NSUInteger rangeIndex = 0;
  // loop building one big string and noting ranges, using optimal iteration letting dictionary feed us matching key and value
  [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL* stop){
    NSString* formattedKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=", key];
    [builder appendString:formattedKey];
    NSUInteger keylen = [formattedKey length];  // allows for anything that happens in the format
    rp[rangeIndex].length = keylen;
    rp[rangeIndex].location = [builder length] - keylen;
    ++rangeIndex;
    [builder appendFormat:@"%@;", obj];
  }];

  // convert built string into one we can add attributes to
  NSMutableAttributedString *result = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:builder];
  // loop adding attributes for the key areas;
  for(rangeIndex = 0; rangeIndex < numPairs; ++rangeIndex)
  {
    [result setAttributes:defaultKeyAttributes range:ranges[rangeIndex]];
  }
  return result;
}
```

calling code using dictionary literals as an example:

```
id test = buildAttributedStringFromDict(
  @{  @"Name":@"Andy",
      @"Role":@"Boss"},
  @{  NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
      NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Papyrus" size:14.0]}
);
```

Debug console output:

```
Printing description of test:
Name={
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x767ed50> font-family: \"Papyrus\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
}Andy;{
}Role={
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x767ed50> font-family: \"Papyrus\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
}Boss;{
}
```

**update - here's a rewritten function using simple concatenation**

```
NSMutableAttributedString* buildAttributedStringFromDict(NSDictionary* dict, NSDictionary* defaultKeyAttributes)
{
  NSUInteger numPairs = [dict count];
  NSUInteger guessInitialCapacity = numPairs * 20;  // use a multiplier based on your domain to avoid string expansions
  NSMutableString* builder = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:guessInitialCapacity];
  NSRange ranges[numPairs];
  NSRange* rp = ranges;  // use pointer to refer to C array because compiler won't let us put __block on it
  __block NSUInteger rangeIndex = 0;
  // loop building one big string and noting ranges, using optimal iteration letting dictionary feed us matching key and value
  [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL* stop){
    [builder appendString:key];
    [builder appendString:@"="];
    NSUInteger keylen = [key length] + 1; // add 1 for = sign
    rp[rangeIndex].length = keylen;
    rp[rangeIndex].location = [builder length] - keylen;
    ++rangeIndex;
    [builder appendString:obj];
    [builder appendString:@";"];
  }];

  // convert built string into one we can add attributes to
  NSMutableAttributedString *result = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:builder];
  // loop adding attributes for the key areas;
  for(rangeIndex = 0; rangeIndex < numPairs; ++rangeIndex)
  {
    [result setAttributes:defaultKeyAttributes range:ranges[rangeIndex]];
  }
  return result;
}
```